# A Turing Machine with undecideable Halting Status not relying on Open Problems

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Is there any turing machine that it is **proovably known to be undecideable**, it has to fullfit the following characteristics:

- **Not rely on Open Problems**/ Conjectures
- Should **not** use the same machine used in diagonalization proof

In other words, is there an alternative proof that Halting problem is undecideable (other than diagonalization)?

Comment: "known to be undecidable" in a particular formal theory, or in the sense that [the set on inputs on which the machine halts] is non-computable? ​ ​

Comment: Is it relevant to say here that $L(M)= \sum^*$ is undecidable, because we do not have a general algorithm that can be applied to this machine to decide whether it is decidable (halts)? If yes, does this support the argument of the halting problem being undecidable?

Comment: But does the proof of that rely on the diagonalization?

Comment: Let *M* be TM that decides $A_{tm}$. Take *M* as subroutine to decide language $S_{tm}$ but since that language is not recursive this leads to contradiction (without diagonalization).

Comment: Would accept it if added with some explaination so that also who don't know what Atm is can understand it